# Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00007FF89D0BB985 (ucrtbased.dll)

Tags: c++

не могу понять , в чём ошибка , пытаюсь просто для начала вывести id из БД oracle

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "occi.h"

    #pragma comment(lib , "oraocci12.lib")


    using namespace std;
    using namespace oracle::occi;

    #define db_user_name "SYSTEM"
    #define db_password "SYSTEM"
    #define db_conn_str "User-PC:1521/orcl"

     int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        try
        {

    Environment* env = Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::OBJECT);

    Connection* conn = env->createConnection(db_user_name, db_password, db_conn_str);

    Statement* stmt = conn->createStatement("Select (id) from tab1");

    ResultSet *rs = stmt->executeQuery();
    int res = 0;
    while (rs->next())
    {
        res = rs->getInt(1);
        cout <<  res << endl;
    }

            stmt->closeResultSet(rs);
            env->terminateConnection(conn);
            Environment::terminateEnvironment(env);
        }
        catch (SQLException &sqlExcp)
        {
            cerr << sqlExcp.getErrorCode() << " " << sqlExcp.getMessage() << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Что-то у вас не видно обработки ошибок. На каком месте происходит падение?

Comment: меня переводит на фаил xstring_insert.h нужен кусочек кода(на который переводит)?

Comment: Нет, было бы куда полезнее узнать в каком месте из приведенного кода это происходит. И какое собственно исключение не обработано.

Comment: это происходит здесь
        Connection* conn = env->createConnection(db_user_name, db_password, db_conn_str);